# External jQuery on specific WordPress page loads, but doesn't run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I will appreaciate you dearly if you help me resolve this issue.

I am trying to load an external jQuery script on a certain page in WordPress. 
The page's title is *program*. jQuery file title is also program.js

This is what I've put into my functions.php

```
function my_scripts_method() {
   wp_register_script('program', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/program.js');
   if(is_page( program )){
     wp_enqueue_script('program');
   }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

This loads the script only on the page *program*, this is working so far, but the script doesn't run, it is not working.

This is my program.js file

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});

$(function() {
    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar-wrapper"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            }, 400);
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            }, 400);
        }
    });


});
```

Thank you for your help, I really can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `jQuery` instead of `$` to call jQuery functions.

Comment: One more question, the sidebar scroolls to infinty when put to "mobile dimensions", is there anyway not to run it on mobile devices?

Comment: Try this work-around : if (screen && screen.width > 480) {
  //sidebar code }